# Polygon shape rendering in LibGdx

Tags: libgdx, polygon, shape-rendering

I created a rectangle polygon like this:

```
polyrect=new Polygon(new float[]{0,0,width,0,width,height,0,height});
polyrect.setOrigin(width,0);
polyrect.setRotation(45f);
polyrect.setPosition(getX(),getY());
shapeRenderer.polygon(polySwatter.getTransformedVertices());
```

It worked well but now I want to draw an inverted triangle like this.

[image]

How can I draw an inverted triangle by this method?

Comment: what do you mean by inverted triangle ?

Comment: added the image@AbhishekAryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set vertices in this way, that gives you inverted triangle.

```
polyrect=new Polygon(new float[]{width/2f,0,width,height,0,height});
polyrect.setOrigin(width,0);
//polyrect.setRotation(45f);
polyrect.setPosition(200,200);
```